# Cross site-publishing without having content based navigation? Any experience with non-default options?

Tags: cross-site-publishing

I'm building an intranet where the **top navigation** is organisational functions (Corporate Services, People, Brand). The homepage has a **Content Search Web Part** showing items of **`ContentType=News`**. The News Content Type is based off **Announcement**, each subsite (each department has a subsite) has a News list.

From my understanding of the cross-site publishing, I can use it to generate a nicely formatted page from **list** content. The question I have is, if I don't want to base my navigation on the content type, ie. News, is there a way to still use cross-site publishing?

eg. My sites are HR, Finance, etc

```
My top Nav is People, Corporate Services, etc
I don't use left nav. (it's hidden)
```

People has sub navigation items that go direct to pages in the subsites

> eg. People\Induction -> HR/Pages/Induction.aspx

I want to show the news **rollup** on the home page which shows all news irrespective of the site. This is easy enough with a Content Search Web Part. When they click on the item in the news rollup, I want them to get a cross-site publishing-like item page that displays the News item, without having to add News to my top navigation.

I know there are a few options with navigation but unsure if I can achieve what I want or if I have to go back to News inheriting from Publishing Page? Another option might be to add it in the navigation but using css to set it to `display:none`?

appreciate any guidance

Comment: You should just be able to go into the term store and mark that you don't want News to show in either the global or the local nav. Then add a CSWP to the page for the items.

Comment: Thanks Rothrock. I read that as soon as you hide the term from navigation via the termstore 'show on navigation' option, it breaks the cross-site publishing. Have you any experience with that? I'm working through it at the moment so will report back my findings.

Comment: Yes we've been using xsp for a bit over a year. You don't hide it on the authoring side, you share the terms and repin into your managed navigation term set.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll go ahead and set it up and trial it. I've played around with the custom URL formatting and now have my head around how it works. Have a page setup that takes the url parameter and displays the content dynamically...  it's starting to make sense to me. I appreciate the replies.

Comment: Yes when I realized that the managed navigation was separate from the xsp that was a big day for what we could do with our site. They work together and connecting the catalog creates a default navigation, but you can modify it add your own pages/links, etc. The managed navigation is one of the best features I think.